# Implementing USB-C PD PHY directly into micro-controller

Tags: power-supply, arduino, usb-c, usb-pd, power-delivery

I want to explore more [USB-C PD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#USB_Power_Delivery), in particular Programmable Power Supply (PPS), to supply my projects with power. There are some good projects<sup>1</sup> using some standard communication (e.g. SPI or I2C) to communicate to as dedicated IC (e.g. [STUSB4500](https://www.st.com/en/interfaces-and-transceivers/stusb4500.html), [FUSB302](https://www.onsemi.com/products/interfaces/usb-type-c/fusb302b#technical-documentation), or [AP33772](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Evaluation-Boards/AP33772-Arduino-I2C-User-Guide-Rev-1.0.pdf)), that then communicates via the CC pins to the PSU (USB-C PD PHY).

However, that means extra cost and extra space for the dedicated communication chip. I guess that's ok for most applications, but I'm curious; from reading [a presentation explaining the details of the USB-C PHY layer](https://web.archive.org/web/20161220102831/http://www.usb.org/developers/presentations/USB_DevDays_Hong_Kong_2016_-_USB_PD.pdf) I would think that it should be rather doable to implement the same logic directly into any better micro-controller (like an ESP32). I say that because the link speed is spec'ed at 300kbps at low impedance at 1.125V (shiftable to and from 3.3V e.g. with [PCA9306](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pca9306.pdf)) via two pins. Sure, then a lot of processing is happening on the logical data to the physical, but that should not be "too hard"<sup>TM</sup> to implement, right? Or am I missing any good reason/complication not to do that?

<sup>1</sup> To name a few:

1. [SparkFun Power Delivery Board - USB-C (Qwiic)](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15801) (STUSB4500)
2. [Mike Rakin's Board](https://www.hackster.io/news/mike-rankin-wants-to-make-usb-c-pd-as-easy-as-1-2-3-with-his-esp32-based-usb-c-pd-trigger-board-39be1086d8b1) + [Github](https://github.com/mike-rankin/ESP32_USB-C_Power_Supply) (STUSB4500)
3. [Ryan Ma's "PD Micro" board](https://www.crowdsupply.com/ryan-ma/pd-micro) + [Github](https://github.com/ryan-ma/PD_Micro) (FUSB302)
4. [Reclaimer Lab's USB-C Power Delivery PHY Breakout Board](https://www.tindie.com/products/reclaimerlabs/usb-c-power-delivery-phy-breakout-board/) or [USB-C Explorer board](https://www.tindie.com/products/reclaimerlabs/usb-c-explorer/) (both FUSB302)
5. [AP33772 Validation Platform Setup](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Evaluation-Boards/AP33772-Arduino-I2C-User-Guide-Rev-1.0.pdf) (AP33772)

**Addition**: Apparently there are a few micro-controllers with built-in capabilities (thanks @Justme), like the STM32G071. There is even an [official discovery kit (STM32G071B-DISCO)](https://st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32g071b-disco.html) and [wiki entry](https://wiki.stmicroelectronics.cn/stm32mcu/wiki/STM32StepByStep:Getting_started_with_USB-Power_Delivery_Source).

Comment: What's the question? You can buy microcontrollers with USB-PD PHY built in already.

Comment: The question is weather it is feasible to do it on standard MCUs. I was not aware there were MCUs that don't need external other ICs for USB-PD. A quick online search didn't yield anything. Could you point me to one/a few?

Comment: Did you try putting "MCU with USB-PD" into your favourite search engine?

Comment: I did. I find a lot of literature talking about such MCUs, but I could not actually find any part numbers yet, except the SMT32 series where it is called "UCPD" (e.g. SMT32G0, but I have a hard time confirming that you really don't need any peripheral ICs). But ok, let's keep it at that. Do you know if there is any arduino-compatible ones? I could really not find any info on that.

Answer (score 4):

I've done that with the benefits as you state. This is purely anecdotal, but hey, one data point :)

Most notably: I can buy the MCUs without PD PHY functionality, but the applicable ones (for my use) *with* PD PHY are vaporware in practice. Furthermore, I need the rather specialized peripheral set on the microcontroller I already use, so switching to a different uC is not possible. Even further, PD is just a tiny bit of the overall device functionality in my case, so choosing an MCU based on that is a bit of a stretch.

There are stand-alone USB PD interface chips with SPI or I2C MCU interface, but they don't quite do what I need. So if you can use those - definitely don't overlook them.

The PD PHY discrete hardware is about a dollar's worth of discrete mosfets and resistors and such. Looks scary on the schematic, but occupies a dozen or two mm^2 on the board (using tiniest parts possible). Sure, doing discrete designs takes some effort, but these days industry-strength SPICE is free-as-in-beer, so that's a good start.

And if we can't buy discrete small signal mosfets anymore, the world is ending, so no need to worry about USB PD, as I usually say.

Level shifter ICs are a wonderful thing if they do what you need for the price you can afford and with a shipping date that works for you. I often go with discrete parts because they are always available, and I'm comfortable enough putting them together. It's probably a rare sight nowadays to see a mostly digital product with dozens of discrete BJTs/mosfets in it, but this strategy has worked for me. It may *not* work for you - keep that in mind, and I'm far from suggesting it as some magic bullet. It's a tradeoff, with factors different for everyone.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Have you shared your design and firmware somewhere? I would be more than curious about it!

Comment: @3244611user Sorry, I don't have the rights to that design, it was contract work

Answer (score 1):

Indeed STM32 series (such as G0/G4/H5/L5) has built-in UCPD peripherals (USB PD controller). You can have a look on the solution at https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/ecosystems/stm32-usb-c.html. Br